# Starting camel route from XML DSL dynamically

Tags: xml, spring, apache-camel

I am trying to conditionally start the route in XML DSL based on boolean value in property file. But it's kind of not working. I am not sure if it's right way of doing it. Any help is appreciated, Thanks :)

This is my blueprint.xml

```
<bean id="bridgePropertyPlaceholder" class="org.apache.camel.spring.spi.BridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:property.properties"/>
</bean>

<camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">


    <route autoStartup="${isTrue}">
        <from uri="pipe:prs:P" />
        <choice>
            <when>
                <simple>${headers.headerName} == 'DR91'</simple>
                <process ref="reqType"></process>
                <to uri="direct-vm:pipeRequestDR91" />
            </when>
            <when>
                <simple>${headers.headerName} == 'DR93'</simple>
                <process ref="reqType"></process>
                <to uri="direct-vm:pipeRequestDR93" />
            </when>
        </choice>
    </route>
```

This is my property file - property.properties

```
isTrue=true
```

The error I am getting says:

```
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: 
org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route 
route1: Route(route1)[[From[pipe:prs:P]] -> [Choice[[When[simple{${h... 
because of Error parsing [${isTrue}] as a Boolean.
```

Comment: You tagged your question with `blueprint-osgi` but you are using the Spring `BridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. I think either your tagging is wrong or your use of the BridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.

Comment: Yeah, I tagged it wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use Camel's property placeholder syntax which is `{{xxx}}`, eg do

```
 <route autoStartup="{{isTrue}}">
```

Comment: Thanks Claus :) So this worked, now I am into some other issue. Since it starts the route  to check if it will work when started again, it triggers my bean . Can we avoid that ?                                                                                                        
    <from uri="pipe:prs:P" />
    <bean id="pipe" class="com.walmart.producer.WalPipeComponent">
 </bean>

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is yet supported.
See here
http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-use-spring-property-placeholder-with-camel-xml.html